# adding a char in every instance of substring

Tags: c, string

In my following code i have added   "d"   after first   "foo"  in given string. How can i do the same for other instances of  "foo"  ?
Any help is appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void main()
 {
    char haystack[20]="foofoofoofoo",*ptr=haystack,*temp=NULL,*temp1=NULL,needle[]="foo";
    int position,length=strlen(needle);

    ptr=strstr(haystack,needle);

    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {       
            temp=(char *)calloc(strlen(haystack)+100,sizeof(char));
            position=(strstr(haystack,needle)-haystack);
            strncpy(temp,haystack,position+length);
            strcat(temp,"d");
            strcat(temp,strstr(haystack,needle)+length);
            strcpy(haystack,temp);
            ptr+=length;
    }       
   printf("\n%s",haystack);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by Grantly, you have to change you if with a while.

But :

- you should also alloc `temp` outside of the loop
- you should free what you have alloced
- you should search for where you stopped and not from the beginning

It could give :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void main()
 {
    char haystack[20]="foofoofoofoo",*ptr=haystack,*temp=NULL,*temp1=NULL,needle[]="foo";
    int position,length=strlen(needle);

    temp=(char *)calloc(strlen(haystack)+100,sizeof(char));


    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {       
            ptr=strstr(ptr,needle);
            if (ptr == NULL) break;
            position=ptr-haystack;
            strncpy(temp,haystack,position+length);
            temp[position + length] = '\0';
            strcat(temp,"d");
            strcat(temp,ptr+length);
            strcpy(haystack,temp);
            ptr+=length + 1;
    }       
   printf("\n%s",haystack);  

   free (temp);
 }
```

And output is as expected : `foodfoodfoodfood`

Comment: thanx  it took half a day to find the solution for me thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop instead of your if(ptr!=NULL) .  Like this:

```
void main()
 {
    char haystack[20]="foofoofoofoo",*ptr=haystack,*temp=NULL,*temp1=NULL,needle[]="foo";
    int position,length=strlen(needle);
ptr=strstr(haystack,needle);

while (ptr!=NULL)
  {       
        temp=(char *)calloc(strlen(haystack)+100,sizeof(char));
        position=(strstr(haystack,needle)-haystack);
        strncpy(temp,haystack,position+length);
        strcat(temp,"d");
        strcat(temp,strstr(haystack,needle)+length);
        strcpy(haystack,temp);
        free(temp);  // free as soon as finished with it
        printf("\n%s",haystack);  
        ptr=strstr(ptr+length,needle);  // search again from position 'length' 
                                        // further into the current position in the string
                                        //  or if its not found, then ptr will be NULL
                                        //ptr+=length;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to free any dynamically allocated variables like temp.  I have not compiled this to test it - but I think you will get the idea

Also, you can get the position that the string is found by subtracting the pointers. ie

```
position= ptr - haystack; // gives 0 based 'index'
```

Comment: it will give the output  "foodddfoofoofoo" which is not proper.

Comment: Well for one - you never stated what your exact output was supposed to be. Two, we are not going to do all your homework for you.  You can make adjustments.... Post your modified attempts so we can see your progress